# CSV Module: How to add preceding comma to subsequent appends?

Tags: python, csv

**tldr;**
When writing to csv, how do I ensure the last element of a previous write is separated from the first element of a subsequent write by a comma and not a new line?

I am currently trying to collect followers data with a list of Twitter users using Tweepy. In the code below, you can see that I'm using pagination as some users have a lot of followers. I'm trying to put all the followers into a csv file for each user, however when I test this code and inspect the csv, I can see there's ***only a new line between page writes, but no commas***. I do not want improper csv format to come back and bite me later in this project.

```
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids,screen_name=username).pages():
    with open(f'output/{username}.csv', 'a') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(page)
```

I've thought of enumerating the pages:

```
for i, page in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids,screen_name=username).pages()):
```

and doing something like `if i > 0`, add comma at end of the current file. This way feels inefficient, as I'd have to open, write a `','`, and close the file each time this happens and I need every second I can save for this project.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what the problem is. I'd say: collect all data in a list, then pass it to `csv.writer` and let it deal with newlines and commas.

Comment: I also don't understand what you're trying to do. The CSV file format doesn't support "pagination" (so that's not something the `csv` module supports).

Comment: `writerow(page)` seems flawed to me. I would think that one page contains *multiple* rows.

Comment: If you want all the information in one row, read the information until you have all the columns, and *then* call `writerow`.